Training data for chatGPT wont work correctly
I am trying to train a model in chatGPT (chatGPT-3.5-turbo-1106) for my cleaning business. based on the documentation I created and uploaded the training data successfully, but the answer I am getting is totally different that what I had in my training data. Here are the sample:
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "Our car cleaning service offers different packages based on your needs."}, {"role": "user", "content": "What does your car cleaning service include?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Our car cleaning service includes three options: 1) Exterior Wash. 2) Exterior Wash & Wax. 3) Interior and Exterior Detail with Wash and Wax. You can choose the package that best suits your preferences and requirements."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "We ensures the safety and reliability of our cleaning services."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Are you insured and bonded for your cleaning service?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "Yes, we are insured and bonded."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "Our staff are capable of handling basic handyman tasks."}, {"role": "user", "content": "Are you licensed to work on electrical or appliances at home?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "No, we can only work on simple electrical issues."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "We makes tipping easy and convenient for customers."}, {"role": "user", "content": "How do you handle tips for the cleaning staff?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "You can tip in person to the staff or on our website."}]}
{"messages": [{"role": "system", "content": "Our cancellation policy ensures flexibility and convenience for our clients."}, {"role": "user", "content": "What is your cancellation policy?"}, {"role": "assistant", "content": "You can cancel 24 hours before the scheduled service."}]}

I tried different version of chatGPT, Also I revised the answers and system content number  of times with no luck

You can only have one "messages" key. And it is usual to have just one entry for the "system" role. So this would give you:
"messages": [
    {
      "role": "system",
      "content": "Our car cleaning service offers ....
       We ensure the safety ...
       etc"
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "What does your car cleaning service include?"
    },
    {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "Our car cleaning service includes ..."
    },
    {
      "role": "user",
      "content": "Are you insured ...?"
    },
    {
      "role": "assistant",
      "content": "Yes, we are ...."
    },

etc
]


Thanks , Lee.  I will revise my data and try it.

Did this approach work for you?
